# MatplotlibDepricationWarning with PyQt5 tutorial

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt5

I tried PyQt5 tutorials with [this site](https://pythonspot.com/tag/pyqt5/page/2/).

In this site, there is a sample code which import matplotlib.
I tried that code, then I could get the PyQt window. It's the same one in that site.
But I get following warning.

```
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance. In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned. Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.warnings.warn(message, mplDeprecation, stacklevel=1)
```

Here is a code related to matplotlib from the site.

```
class PlotCanvas(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
        self.plot()


    def plot(self):
        data = [random.random() for i in range(25)]
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(data, 'r-')
        ax.set_title('PyQt Matplotlib Example')
        self.draw()
```

Why does this warning occur ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deletre the line `ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)`,

and replaced attribute `ax` to `self.axes`.

This solved the warning !

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two axes instances:

```
self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

which is created the moment you create a class object. The second being

```
ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
```

which is created when you use the class object to call the `plot` method. Most likely due to this reason you get this warning. Also, I believe the following line in your `plot` method

```
self.figure.add_subplot(111)
```

should be written as (using `self.fig`)

```
self.fig.add_subplot(111)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried this solution before asking this question. But, it does't work. Using self.fig, AttributeError occured. 'PlotCanvas' object has no attribute 'fig'. How can I solve this problem ?